# PHP session not destroying or unsetting

Tags: php, session, web, authentication, session-variables

I have this following PHP code for checking login in my index.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect("***", "***", "***", "***");

$fbid_check=$_SESSION['loginid_session'];
$fbphoto_session=$_SESSION['loginphoto_session'];

$fbname_sql=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT fb_name FROM uni_users WHERE fb_id='$fbid_check' ");
$name_fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($fbname_sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$fbname_session=$name_fetch['fb_name'];

if(isset($fbname_session))
 {
    header("location: http://www.uniwink.com/landing/profile.php");
 }
mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

This checks for login and redirects to profile.php which has the following PHP code in the header to check for login

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("****", "****", "****", "****");

session_start();
$fbid_check=$_SESSION['loginid_session'];
$fbphoto_session=$_SESSION['loginphoto_session'];

$fbname_sql=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT fb_name FROM uni_users WHERE fb_id='$fbid_check' ");
$name_fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($fbname_sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$fbname_session=$name_fetch['fb_name'];

if(!isset($fbname_session))
{
   header("location: http://www.uniwink.com/landing");
}

mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

And I have this following logout.php which is called from profile.php

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['loginid_session']);
unset($fbname_session);
session_destroy();
header("location: http://www.uniwink.com/landing");
exit();

?>
```

The problem is after logout, it still goes into profile.php . It is as if like the session is not destroyed at all. The thing is it was working properly until yesterday and happened all of a sudden. Thanks

Comment: try remove the unset($fbname_session); its not defined anywhere on the logout page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the session.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loginid_session'])) 
{
    header("location: http://www.uniwink.com/landing/profile.php");
}
else
{
    header("location: http://www.uniwink.com/landing");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. I should have checked the session instead of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

try to move `session_start();` above the mysql connection.

change

```
$con = mysqli_connect("****", "****", "****", "****");
session_start();
```

to

```
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("****", "****", "****", "****");
```

also use isset with session

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loginid_session'])){ 
   .....
}
```

Comment: yeah I should have used the if condition with the session instead of the variable. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

try adding the following to your logout;

```
$_SESSION = array();
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies"))
{
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}
```

Note: This will destroy the session - not just the session data.